# Text Rendering WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, textures, webgl

I am trying to give text labels to different elements in a 2D image. The 2d elements are obtained through projection from 3d. I have certain element ids that I want to include as text labels. I have been trying this for 2 days with no luck. I dont know what is going wrong. Here is the function that does the rendering:

```
function drawOverlayTriangles()
{
    if (overlay.numElements <= 0)
    return;

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.aVertexPosition);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.aVertexColor);

    // Turn off textures
    //gl.vertexAttrib1f(shaderProgram.aHasTexture, 0.0);

    // Upload Projection, ModelView matrices
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.uMVMatrix, false, pMVMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.uPMatrix, false, perspM);

    for (var i = 0; i < overlay.numElements; i++) {
        // Upload overlay vertices                      
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, overlayVertices[i]);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.aVertexPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        // Upload overlay colors
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, overlayTriangleColors[i]);    
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.aVertexColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.setAttribute("id","canvas");
        canvas.width="512";
        canvas.height="512";
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var text = "element";//overlay.elementIDs[i];

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);

        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,255)';
        ctx.lineWidth = 2.5;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.save();
        ctx.font = 'bold 80px Verdana';

        var leftOffset = ctx.canvas.width/2;
        var rightOffset = ctx.canvas.height/2;
        ctx.strokeText(text,leftOffset,rightOffset);
        ctx.fillText(text,leftOffset,rightOffset);
        ctx.restore();

        var texttexture=gl.createTexture();

        gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,texttexture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,canvas);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);           
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);



    // Draw overlay
       gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, overlay.elementNumVertices[i]);
       }

  gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.aVertexPosition);
  gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.aVertexColor);
  }
```

I am a beginner in Webgl and since I only need 2d text labels for 2d projected elements, please tell me if there is a simpler way to do this.

This is the function that calls the rendering function :

```
function saveModelImage(separateElementImages)
{
var glCanvas = document.getElementById("glCanvas");
glCanvas.width = 2144;
glCanvas.height = 1424;

var fov = deg2rad(60);
if(cameraIndex > -1)
{
    var f = model.cameras[cameraIndex].f;
    glCanvas.width = camImageWidths[cameraIndex];
    glCanvas.height = camImageHeights[cameraIndex];
    console.info("w: " + glCanvas.width + "  h: " + glCanvas.height);
    fov = 2 * Math.atan(0.5 * glCanvas.height / f);
}

gl.viewportWidth = glCanvas.width;
gl.viewportHeight = glCanvas.height;
gl.aspectRatio = gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight;
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
gl.viewportCenter = vec3.fromValues(gl.viewportWidth / 2.0, gl.viewportHeight / 2.0);
updateBoundingRect();

mat4.ortho(orthoM, -gl.aspectRatio, gl.aspectRatio, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 100.0);
mat4.perspective(perspM, fov, gl.aspectRatio, 0.5, 10000);
// we need to pass in the cameraID to this function
// using camera.ID, we will find the accurate width and height to use for glCanvas.
// then the gl.aspectRatio could be set as above
// and FOV (in rad) = 2 atan(0.5 glCanvas.height / camera.f)


if(separateElementImages == true)
{
    //something
}
else
{
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawOverlayTriangles();

    var imageUrl = glCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);

    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', imageUrl);
    pom.setAttribute('download', 'image_C' + cameraIndex + '.jpg');

    document.body.appendChild(pom);

    pom.click();

    document.body.removeChild(pom);
}
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Since this is webgl, and you only want 2d text, you could just overlay regular html dom elements for your labels - you need to calculate the screen position that you want to display them at based on the 3d location, then position your labels per-frame.

Comment: I tried that but didnt work. I am confused as to what is gl and glcanvas. I am not sure which one I need to use and if that is what is affecting. The drawarrays function works fine though

Comment: `gl` is the rendering context, `glcanvas` is the `<canvas>` dom object on your web page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is either draw on a 2d canvas over your webgl canvas or move HTML elements over your webgl canvas.

Drawing on a 2d canvas over a WebGL Canvas

```js
var underCanvas = document.getElementById("under");
var overCanvas = document.getElementById("over");

// get a webgl context for the under canvas.
var gl = underCanvas.getContext("webgl");

// get a webgl context for the over canvas.
var ctx = overCanvas.getContext("2d");

var radius = 70;
var clock;
var x;
var y;

function render() {
  
  clock = Date.now() * 0.001;
 
  
  x = Math.floor(Math.cos(clock) * radius + gl.canvas.width  * 0.5);
  y = Math.floor(Math.sin(clock) * radius + gl.canvas.height * 0.5);
  
  
  drawWebGLStuff(gl);
  drawCanvas2DStuff(ctx);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();


function drawWebGLStuff(gl) {
  // I'm using the SCISSOR because it's the simplest thing
  gl.disable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  gl.scissor(
     Math.max(0, x - 10),
     Math.max(0, y - 10),
     20,
     20);
  gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
  gl.clearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

function drawCanvas2DStuff() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillText("Hello World", x, ctx.canvas.height - y);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#under {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
/* put "over" on top of "under" */
#over {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="under"></canvas>
<canvas id="over"></canvas>
```

Drawing by moving an HTML element over the canvas

```js
var underCanvas = document.getElementById("under");
var overCanvas = document.getElementById("over");

// get a webgl context for the under canvas.
var gl = underCanvas.getContext("webgl");

// make a div for text
var textDiv = document.createElement("div");
textNode = document.createTextNode("");
textDiv.className = "over";
textDiv.appendChild(textNode);
document.body.appendChild(textDiv);


var radius = 70;
var clock;
var x;
var y;

function render() {
  
  clock = Date.now() * 0.001;
 
  
  x = Math.floor(Math.cos(clock) * radius + gl.canvas.width  * 0.5);
  y = Math.floor(Math.sin(clock) * radius + gl.canvas.height * 0.5);
  
  
  drawWebGLStuff(gl);
  moveTextDiv();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
render();


function drawWebGLStuff(gl) {
  // I'm using the SCISSOR because it's the simplest thing
  gl.disable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  gl.scissor(
     Math.max(0, x - 10),
     Math.max(0, y - 10),
     20,
     20);
  gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
  gl.clearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

function moveTextDiv() {
  textDiv.style.left = x + "px";
  textDiv.style.top  = (gl.canvas.height - y) + "px";
  textNode.nodeValue = clock.toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  overflow: none;
  position: absolute;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#under {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
.over {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<body>
<canvas id="under"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: [Here's a few more examples](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-text-html.html)